# Perl While STDIN.... Don't understand still

Tags: perl

I don't understand. That's but don't work with function.

```
else{
    print ("Falsch. Bitte nochmals geben Sie es!\n");
    $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp ($name);
    while ($name ne $fullname){
        print ("Falsch. Bitte nochmals geben Sie es!\n");
        $name = <STDIN>;
        chomp ($name);
        if ($sceret ne $sceretpassword){
            print ("Falsch Passwort!\n");
            $sceret = <STDIN>;
            chomp ($sceret);
        }
    }
}
```

Hm. What should i this just? pls help me. thankful very much!

[image]

Comment: Deine Frage ist nicht klar. Willst du den Benutzer immer den Name und das Passwort fragen, bis sie richtig sind?/Your question is not clear. Do you want to keep asking the user for name and password until they are correct?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What problem are you having?

Comment: He wants to repeatedly ask user for input until the name and password are right

Comment: That `if` test is applied before the `password` is read. That won't work very well!

Comment: Im Bild: "Geben Sie deine Passwort" und "Geben Sie deine Name". Die Grammatik ist hier komisch. (The German grammar is a little off?)

Comment: @Arc676 obviously OP is neither fluent in German nor English. We're not proof-reading.SE ;)

Comment: I rolled your question back to the mixed/German version. It's fine like that. You don't have to have English text in your code. But next time please post the code as code, not as a screenshot. It's nice and colorful, but we cannot copy and run it. ;)

Comment: Also, Welcome to Stack Overflow and to the Perl tag! :)

Comment: @simbabque Thank you for welcome. I'm feeling well for the welcome to and stack overflow perl tag! After I need to asked stack overflow always. Stack Overflow is helpful really. Happines. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you ver much for helpful! But I found a good code. It's good function.

```
my $fullname = "Markus Buergi";
my $sceretpassword = "Alpiq";
my $get_name = "Hello, your Name is ";
my $get_password = "Password is correct!";
my $wrong_name = "Wrong, Name again: ";
my $wrong_password = "Wrong, Password: ";
```

## Second Name is correct, further this

```
else{
    print $wrong_name;
    $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp ($name);
    while ($name ne $fullname){
        print $wrong_name;
        $name = <STDIN>;
        chomp ($name);
    }

    print $get_name, $name, "\n";

    do {
        print $wrong_password;
        $sceret = <STDIN>;
        chomp ($sceret);
    }
    until ($sceret eq $sceretpassword);
    print $get_password, "\n";
    exit;   
}
```

It's looked good function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing something odd.

You loop while "name" doesn't match "fullname".

But you test the password *before* you ask for the passsword.:

```
if ($sceret ne $sceretpassword){
    print ("Falsch Passwort!\n");
    $sceret = <STDIN>;
    chomp ($sceret);
}
```

That'll technically work, because if you:

- login with the correct password - it will fail.
- then login again - the previous password will still be 'stored' and it'll work.

That's a bit strange.

Perhaps you meant:

```
while ($name ne $fullname
    or $sceret ne $sceretpassword ) {
    print ("Incorrect login\n");
    print "name:\n";
    $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp ($name);
    print "Password:\n";
    $sceret = <STDIN>;
    chomp ($sceret);
}
```

This will continue to loop until someone gets the right combination of name and password.

Answer (score 1):

## Für deutsche Übersetzung siehe unten.

You can use a `while` loop to repeat until a condition is met.

You checked if the password was correct before you asked the user for it.

Here, two loops are used. In the other answer, only one is used. It's shorter, but you need `next` to ask the user again in between if any data is wrong.

```
print "Enter name: ";
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp $name;

# if the name is correct the first time, this won't run
while ($name ne $fullname){
    print "Wrong. Enter again: ";
    $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp $name;
}
print "Enter password: ";
$secret = <STDIN>;
chomp $secret;
while ($secret ne $secretpassword){
    print "Wrong. Enter again: ";
    $secret = <STDIN>;
    chomp $secret;
}
# if you are here, the name and password are correct
```

Using `next` and `last`:

```
# Infinite loop
while (1){
    print "Enter name: ";
    $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp $name;
    if ($name ne $fullname){
        print "Wrong.\n";
        # jumps to the next _round_ in the while (1) loop
        next;
    }
    print "Enter password: ";
    $secret = <STDIN>;
    chomp $secret;
    if ($secret ne $secretpassword){
        print "Wrong.\n";
        next;
    }
    # break out of the loop
    last;
}
# name and password are correct
```

---

Du kannst `while` benutzen, um etwas zu tun, bis es `wahr` ist.

Du hast das Passwort kontrolliert bevor du es abgefragt hast. Hier wird `while` zweimal benutzt. In der anderen Antwort wirst es nur einmal benutzt. Sie ist kürzer, aber du brauchst `next`, um den Benutzer die Daten zu fragen, wenn etwas inzwischen falsch ist.

```
print "Name eingeben: ";
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp $name;

# wenn der Name richtig ist, wird die Schleife gar nicht ausgefuehrt
while ($name ne $fullname){
    print "Falscher Name. Nochmal: ";
    $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp $name;
}
print "Passwort eingeben: ";
$secret = <STDIN>;
chomp $secret;
while ($secret ne $secretpassword){
    print "Falsches Passwort. Nochmal: ";
    $secret = <STDIN>;
    chomp $secret;
}
# wenn wir hier ankommen war beides richtig
```

Wenn du lieber `next` und `last` benutzen willst:

```
# Endlosschleife
while (1){
    print "Name eingeben: ";
    $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp $name;
    if ($name ne $fullname){
        print "Falsch.\n";
        # zur naechsten _Runde_ in der while (1)-Schleife
        next;
    }
    print "Passwort eingeben: ";
    $secret = <STDIN>;
    chomp $secret;
    if ($secret ne $secretpassword){
        print "Falsch.\n";
        next;
    }
    # aus der while-Schleife herausspringen
    last;
}
# wenn wir hier ankommen war beides richtig
```

Comment: Thanks! That's good! Name is correct, then the Password is wrong. But stay the Password ask further. Name is stay correct without repetition. I did try this further.

Comment: I find the mix of German and English incredibly hard to read. Maybe the answer would be better to understand if you separate the English and the German in two parts, put the full answer in English first and start with a "Deutsch siehe unten". It's nice to try to include answers in a common language when you feel OP is strugling with English, but keep in mind that others should benefit from the content too. I have had situations where I wanted to include explanation in German, but have decided against it because it's just too messy. SO is not designed for that. Chat might help though.

Comment: simbabque , i understand! i'will change german to english. there's no problem. I hope there helpful. thank you. :-)

Comment: @simbabque Just out of curiosity, do you speak German? If you want, you can edit my answer, possibly improving the word choice. I myself am far from fluent. Markus: I think he meant my answer, not your original question.

Comment: @Markus yes, I meant the answer. Your question was in English, that's all fine. And it's obvious you are not German either. :)

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that it's noble to try to help someone by switching to their language, but legibility should come first. I'll give the edit a try. If you don't like it, please roll it back.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks for the edit. I can get some good vocab from it, in case another German question pops up.

Comment: No problem, though I'm not used to writing technical in German. I avoid it. All my `$work` stuff is in English because I think all those _Anglizismen_ are horrible and it hurts when I read to many of them. On the other hand, I constantly use them when I talk. Hmm.